# Hostería vs Pensión vs Hospedería

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sustantivos, diferencias-entre-palabras

Una [hostería](https://dle.rae.es/hoster%C3%ADa) es

> Casa donde se da comida y alojamiento mediante pago.

mientras que una [pensión](https://dle.rae.es/pensi%C3%B3n?) es

> Casa donde se reciben huéspedes mediante precio convenido.

y una [hospedería](https://dle.rae.es/hospeder%C3%ADa?) es

> Casa destinada al alojamiento de visitantes o viandantes, establecida por personas particulares, institutos o empresas.

Las definiciones son parecidas. ¿Son sinónimos o hay alguna diferencia sutil?

Answer (score 3):

Hostería u hostal suele ser un establecimiento privado de paso más bien turístico, mientras que en una pensión puede haber clientes por un tiempo determinado. Hay gente que vive en pensiones mientras que en un hostal es raro encontrar una situación así.

Una hospedería, palabra no muy utilizada, es un sitio donde un particular ofrece hospedaje temporal sin ser este una empresa dedicada a la hostelería.

Comment: *Pensión* y *hospedería*, ambos términos están en desuso con las acepciones que pregunta el OP. Difícilmente alguien prefiera usar esos términos antes que *residencia*, *casa* o *departamento*; independientemente de que el dueño ofrezca alojamiento o no.

Comment: @tac Hay que tomar precaución con afirmaciones tan taxativas en un sitio de preguntas y respuestas global como SE. El español es un idioma que se habla en gran cantidad de países, tanto de habla hispana como no; lo que es admisible como uso correcto en ciertos lugares puede estar fuera de contexto en otros. *Pensión* es una palabra de uso corriente y habitual. *Hospedería* es más utilizada en textos formales siendo reemplazada por *hospedaje* en léxico informal.

Comment: @Danielillo ¿Pero miraste en las publicaciones de los propios usuarios a ver en cuántas aparece alguna de las dos palabras? No sé no sé, te dejo con el beneficio de la duda. Pero si alguien me viene a ofrecer una 'pensión', mis pupilas van a dilatarse y se me va a caer la baba esperando la guita lo antes posible 

Comment: No me guío por publicaciones sino por la vida real. Abre Google Maps y pon la palabra "pensión".

Comment: @tac: Aunque sean palabras en desuso (que por los otros comentarios no parece el caso), la pregunta hace referencia al **significado** (pasado o presente), no al uso.

Comment: Que raro porque ya busqué en maps, lo único que hace es mostrarme casas departamentos y hoteles que están en venta. Parece que google asocia la palabra ‘pensión’ a estas cosas, pero los casos en donde los propios usuarios que ofrecen sus lugares los nombraron así los cuento con la mano. De todas formas, ya había votado + porque las definiciones están bien

Answer (score 2):

La palabra pensión en cierta parte de México está relacionada con el hospedaje de personas, y tiene una connotación de largo plazo, usualmente atribuida a casas particulares donde además ofrecen servicios de alimentos, limpieza, lavandería, etcétera; sin embargo también la suelen utilizar para significar el resguardo de automóviles, también con la connotación de largo plazo, usualmente a través del pago de una cuota fija por comodidad, seguridad o falta de espacio para poder dejarlos en la vía pública.

Añadiendo, también se utiliza la palabra pensión para lugares al cuidado de mascotas por periodos extendidos.

Hospedería me parece que es el abuso descriptivo de un lugar o negocio dedicado al hospedaje, personalmente no la había leído o escuchado.